# Splitting a string into blocks

Tags: ruby, string

I was wondering how I could program something to split a string into blocks of five using Ruby. Help much appreciated.

Comment: Have a look at [String#split](http://ruby-doc.org/core-2.2.0/String.html#method-i-split)  and [String#slice](http://ruby-doc.org/core-2.2.0/String.html#method-i-slice) - one of them should guide you to build rest of logic

Comment: Welcome to SO.  Please take some time to read http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask.  It will help you post better questions and (hopefully) get good answers.

Answer (score 1):

You can use `String#scan` method to achieve it. E.g `'string_test'.scan(/.{1,5}/)`

Comment: `'abc'.scan /.{5}/ #⇒ []` I doubt this is an expected result.

Comment: @mudasobwa, thanks for it. I have amended the answer and I think it should be ok now.

Comment: Maybe `.{,5}` in case it's an empty string, but aside from that, I like this.